# How to turn a tab-separated table into tagged sections with command line tools?

Tags: text-processing, awk

That is, turn this:

```
Column_A   Column_B   Column_C
--------   --------   --------
value-1a   value-1b   value-1c
value-2a   value-2b   value-2c
```

into this:

```
Column_A: value-1a
Column_B: value-1b
Column_C: value-1c

Column_A: value-2a
Column_B: value-2b
Column_C: value-2c
```

Answer (score 4):

If the above table is in a file named `table`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) header[i]=$i }
       NR>2  { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print header[i] ": " $i
               print ""}' table
```

Headers are collected in the first line. The second line is skipped. The remaining lines are printed as shown.

It's not very elegant but does the job, I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\n"; ORS="\n\n" }
NR == 1 { split($0,tags) }
NR > 2 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s: %s%s", tags[i], $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Column_A: value-1a
Column_B: value-1b
Column_C: value-1c

Column_A: value-2a
Column_B: value-2b
Column_C: value-2c
```